# Can I exclude content from Thunderbird's global search?

Tags: thunderbird

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/global-search

I want to **only search for email** and exclude RSS feeds, chat messages and everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it appears that exceptions can only be configured on per-folder, not per-account basis (right click a folder > properties > general information):

[image: Thunderbird folder properties]